# Wrong format in Drive API when exporting spreadsheet as CSV

Tags: python, csv, google-drive-api

I was glad to see that the drive api supports exporting spreadsheets as CSV files, and it seems to work fine. However, it does not work for all docs. I'm using the exact same code for two different docs and one of them is returned in the proper CSV format. The other one is returned in xlsx format, even though the format is specified as CSV.

Here's the code used:

```
export_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/exportid=%s&exportFormat=csv" % key
_response, content = self.drive_api._http.request(export_url)
```

Also verified the exportLink for the doc, and it lists the csv format and the exact same URL as above. Still, it's returning in xlsx format.

Has anyone noticed this? Bug in the API, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Anders

Answer (score 0):

Yes there was a bug in Google SpreadSheet API yesterday. Google instantly took that into account and fixed it till evening. Developers were experiencing 500 and 403's.

Hope the issue is resolved at your end too.